# req.session.id different to req.session._id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to understand why this:

```
req.session._id = doc._id;
req.session.id = doc._id;

console.log(typeof req.session._id); // object
console.log(typeof req.session.id); // string

console.log(req.session._id); // 4oqTbA06DcK9cIiU3tnK62Ic.0puZ9uPnIaghMBIQKaIbhIHYzeP8wtS3MXnzpi+yC1c
console.log(req.session.id); // 4fb01ad2ca42e9552d000001
```

So, when i want to do this:

```
var myID = req.session._id, myIDm = new BSON.ObjectID(myID); // don't bug
var myID = req.session.id, myIDm = new BSON.ObjectID(myID); // bug: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

Thank you for tell me all information about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `_id` is autogenerated by mongodb and is of type `ObjectID` which can be passed to `BSON.ObjectID()` and you get new `ObjectId` with the same id. The `id` attribute is not managed by mongodb and if you put this value to `BSON.ObjectID()` constructor, it raises error. The expected string must be 12 bytes or hex encoded binary of length 24 (allowed chars are a-f, A-F, 0-9). Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, but why _req.session._id_ = **object** and with the variable id: **string**. Doc._id don't change..

Comment: They are two different objects, the id is created by express or connect session, _id is managed by mongodb.

Comment: YES!! exactly! **i forget** (-_-' omg) that the variable `id` was used by **express** or **connect**. So, with other variable (e.g: iid, _id ..etc) it work! Thanks you!